# Unprotecting PowerPoint PPAM file not working

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I just tried to edit a PPAM of mine that I lost the PPTM of.  I tried the hexeditor fix changing the DPX CMX and CG values but when I open I try to set the properties in VBA all I get is the password prompt.  I'm on the latest version of Microsoft 365.

Thanks